# Abstracting DataTables and DataRows

Tags: datatable, abstract, abstraction, datarow

Every class in my BLL has the following function:

```
private void FillList()
{
    MyDataSet.MyDataTable dt = MyTableAdapter.GetList();
    foreach (MyDataSet.MyDataRow row in dt)
    {
       this.List.Add(new MyClass(row));
    }

}
```

MyDataSet is the same for all classes.

MyTableAdapter, MyDataTable, MyDataRow, MyClass - all change for every class.

Still, it looks like duplicating code to me.

How can I make FillList an abstract function and inherit it by every class?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you REALLY mean abstract? Or do you want to implement a method in an abstract (or not) parent that could be called from all its children?

Comment: Both solutions are good.

Comment: Just another questions: what is the purpose of DataSet?

Comment: DataSet contains all the types DataTables and TabelAdapters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an `abstract` method you must change its visibility beacause abstract methods must be implemented in concrete classes (children). The children must by consequence have access to this method.

Here is the conde in the parent class (always abstract):

```
abstract class Parent
    {
        protected abstract void FillList();
    }
```

and here is an example of code of achild class (implementation)

```
class Child:Parent
{
    protected override void FillList()
    {
        MyDataSet.MyDataTable dt = MyTableAdapter.GetList();
        foreach (MyDataSet.MyDataRow row in dt)
        {
           this.List.Add(new MyClass(row));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see here the abstract method is more a contract ensuring that tha children must implement it. (Note that you could  use [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for such a purpose.)

Amore useful solution,  is creating common parents for `MyDataTable` (all implementing `GetList`), MyDataRow... and split the method

```
class Parent
{
    protected void FillList()
    {
        MyDataSet.MyParentDataTable dt = MyParentTableAdapter.GetList();
        foreach (MyDataSet.MyParentDataRow row in dt)
        {
           this.List.Add(getMyClass(row));
        }
    }
    protected abstract MyParentClass getNewMyClass(MyDataSet.MyParentDataRow row);

}

class Child:Parent
{

    protected override MyParentClass getNewMyClass(MyDataSet.MyParentDataRow row)
    {
          return new MyClass(row)
    }

}
```

The last example was made quick and dirty : you have to List accessible from the children and you should consider using generics if you can but it can give you an idea of what is possible.

Comment: @Yevgenigrinberg I must admit I am afraid this is not what you expected but the having a reusable parent method is a bit difficult the way you designed things.